# Unable to login to MySQL instance hosted on AWS ec2

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up a `mysql` database on an aws ec2 instance (SUSE 32-bit with mysql pre-installed). However, I can't log in to mysql as root user:

```
mysql -u root
Access denied
```

without a password, so is there a way of getting one? I believe that root user is blocked and hence should login with `ec2-user`. However, when I do

```
mysql -u ec2-user
```

the user does not have the priviledges to create a database.

I'm a not very familiar with linux, so if I'm simply doing this completely wrong, then do say.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this probably fits better on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: As Dan Grossman says - EC2 is irrelevant here. However, you may have installed your OS off an EC2 image that had mysql installed by default and sets some password on the mysql root account, which you can bypass with information in Dan's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that this server is on EC2 is irrelevant. SUSE and MySQL do not know this. Amazon cannot block anything, you have root access to the server. You recover/change the root password the same as any server, with mysqladmin, or by starting mysqld with `--skip-grant-tables` while you make the change.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql -u root -p`

Then press enter.

Answer (score -1):

I know, this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend using the AWS Relational Database Service.  Amazon will host a MySQL database for you and take care of all the setup, maintenance, scaling, backup, etc.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: ...at the equivalent cost of *several* equivalent servers of your own each month.

Comment: Amazon RDS is expensive if you just want to run a small instance of mysql database.

Comment: ahhh that's why they havent made the setup for mysql seamless as it could be...!

Comment: RDS is somewhat more expensive, certainly not multiple times more expensive.  But if you want it seemless, you could try a MySQL marketplace solution: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007I8JCUG/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-6&qid=1383253840590

Comment: Irrelevant answer. Please try to answer the question.